# How to download an MP3 or ZIP file onto mobile devices

Tags: php, ecommerce, download

I want to be able to download digital goods to smartphone users (music in format .mp3 or .zip). But iPhone and iPad do not allow direct forced downloads.

**How can I provide mobile users with digital downloads?** I use PHP.

The only way I can think of to do this is to use the Dropbox Web API to transfer files to the user's Dropbox account, which then synchronizes with their mobile device.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Android *can* downlaod files from the web.

Comment: are you looking for a code example?

Comment: @elconejito I am just trying to figure out if it's even possible, so yes a code sample would be fine.

Comment: @Hope4You: "answer" = "question"?

Comment: Can someone help me understand what exactly happens when you click a web link pointing to a .zip or .mp3 on an iPhone? Does it simply not work? Does it pop up a security notice and then just bail? I don't have an iphone and I'm wondering if it is simply a matter of sending the correct content-disposition header. Example `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.mp3"');`

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos For a .zip file forced download, it says "You cannot download this" or something like that. That's why I'm trying to figure out how else to do it. For MP3s you also cannot save the file to the user's device.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos update: According to elconejito, it can be done. You can try his suggestion and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but it *is* possible to have a mobile platform (iOS, Android, etc) download a file. With some minor quirks, mobile browsers behave just like their desktop counterparts.

You can provide the user with a direct link like `http://example.com/somefile.zip`

If you need to do some processing via PHP first, it can look like

```
<?php
// can I download this file
if ( $itsoktodownload == true ) {
  // some code here
  header("Location: http://example.com/somefile.zip);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Basically, that code snippet is just redirecting the user to the url of the downloaded file.

If you need something more specific, like you need to force it to download (instead of attempting to "open"), or you need to control the headers sent first, or you are trying to hide the real location of the file (so people can't share the link around), there are many download scripts available via google.

You could ask a more specific question once you've gotten into it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of:

1. A custom application (although, at least on iOS, you won't be able to add mp3s to the main music library on the device)
2. The official stores (iTunes / Google Play / 3rd Party Android Stores)
3. A download the user can access on their desktop and then sync to their mobile device

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for a way to do it directly from the web/PHP.

Answer (score -1):

iDownloads PLUS is great iOS application which helps to download mp3 and Zip files. It also includes many advanced features for zip extract, music playlist and many others additional work.

Comment: -1 How does your answer address the asker's question? Are you affiliated with iDownloads PLUS?

Comment: I don't want the people to have to use a third-party app like this... My only exception, as stated above, may be Dropbox.